# Get random item in array as value with support for plurals

Tags: javascript, i18next

I have resource strings that have this form:

```
MY_VARIATIONS: {
      1: {
         KEY_WITH_COUNT: "{{count}} day remaining",
         KEY_WITH_COUNT_plural: "{{count}} days remaining"
      },
      2: {
         KEY_WITH_COUNT: "{{count}} day to go",
         KEY_WITH_COUNT_plural: "{{count}} days to go"
      }
}
```

Then when I use the function t in my javascript code I do:

```
t('MY_VARIATIONS.1.KEY_WITH_COUNT', {count: daysToGo});
```

but this will select the first item in the array while I want a random one. Is there a way to initialize i18n o adapt the interpolation process to have it return a random item in MY_VARIATIONS? (ideally within i18next init so I don't have to create peripheral code to do that)

Comment: Just FWIW, randomness like this in UI isn't usually a good idea. Perhaps in certain niche situations, though...

Comment: Exactly in UI it's not. In my niche, VUI, it's essential!

Comment: VUI as in voice user interface?

Comment: Yes, thx for the answer below. In GUI users expect uniformity. In VUI they expect variation (or it gets repetitive)

Comment: Interesting! ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it by changing the structure of the resource strings like this:

```
KEY_WITH_COUNT: ['{{count}} day remaining', '{{count}} day to go'],
KEY_WITH_COUNT_plural: ['{{count}} days remaining', '{{count}} days to go']
```

and then initializing i18next and overwriting the t function like:

```
process(callerObject, locale, resourceStrings) {
    const localisationClient = i18n.init({
        lng: locale,
        resources: resourceStrings,
        returnObjects: true
    });
    localisationClient.localise = function localise() {
        const args = arguments;
        const value = i18n.t(...args);
        if (Array.isArray(value)) {
            return value[Math.floor(Math.random() * value.length)];
        }
        return value;
    };
    callerObject.t = function translate(...args) {
        return localisationClient.localise(...args);
    }
}
```

Then I would use it like this:

```
callerObject.t('KEY_WITH_COUNT', {count: 1}); // "1 day remaining"
callerObject.t('KEY_WITH_COUNT', {count: 1}); // "1 day to go"
callerObject.t('KEY_WITH_COUNT', {count: 2}); // "2 days remaining"
callerObject.t('KEY_WITH_COUNT', {count: 2}); // "2 days to go"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get all the keys in `MY_VARIATIONS` via `Object.keys` (since they're all own, enumerable properties), which gives you an array. Then pick a random key from the array and use string concatenation:

```
const keys = Object.keys(MY_VARIATIONS);
t('MY_VARIATIONS.' + keys[Math.floor(Math.random() * keys)] + '.KEY_WITH_COUNT', {count: daysToGo});
```

That assumes the code has access to `MY_VARIATIONS`. Unless the i18next library specifically supports random variations (which seems unlikely), I don't think there's a reasonable way around that.